# Uncheck a checkbox if the (X)-Close Button of the Userform is pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that is activated whenever I check a checkbox that is on the sheet, and if I uncheck it, it is hidden from the screen. The problem is that when I press the red close (X) button from the userform, the checkbox doesn't uncheck, but it should, since the userform is no longer on the screen. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Are you asking for code that unchecks a worksheet checkbox? If so, you need to give more detail, e.g., what kind of checkbox and perhaps a sample of your code. If you already have a Close button that works and you're asking how to make the X act like the close button then take a look at the [QueryClose event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event).

Comment: [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/#Cancelling_the_UserForm) is an example how to use the query close event.

Comment: I have on the sheet a form control checkbox that when checked it displays the userform, and when unchecked it removes the userform from the screen. What i'm asking is how to uncheck the checkbox when the userform is on the screen and its cancel (X) from top right corner is pressed, because after i press this button and the userform closes the checkbox is still checked.

Comment: Why don't you show your code? I expect you have something like Userform1.show in your code. In this way you use the global default instance which yon can but shouldn't. Anyway, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it might not be best practice you could use the following code in the QueryClose event

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                       , CloseMode As Integer)

    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True

    ' Hide the Userform
    Hide

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Checkbox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0

End Sub
```

I assume you do not use an ActiceX-Control and the name of your checkbox is *CheckBox1*

A slightly better way might be to use the following code in a normal module for the checkbox instead of the above code in the userform module. In this way the form does not need to know about a checkbox which called it.

```
Sub Checkbox_code()

Dim f As UserForm1
Dim b As CheckBox

    Set f = New UserForm1
    Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Checkbox1").OLEFormat.Object

    If b.Value = xlOn Then
        f.Show
        b.Value = xlOff
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```